# mongodb : error with insertMany

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to insert multiple 'groups' in a Group collection using insertMany, but it(s always raising an error after the first items is inserted ..

```
>db.groups.insertMany([{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA"},
{"name":"GroupB","description":"Description GroupB"},
{"name":"GroupC","description":"Description GroupC"}])
```

*first item inserted*

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("593ad787da6a6eba2994dfb6"), "name" : "GroupA", 
"description" : "Description GroupA" }
```

**error**

```
2017-06-09T19:14:47.537+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] BulkWriteError: write error at item 1 in bulk operation :
BulkWriteError({
        "writeErrors" : [
                {
                        "index" : 1,
                        "code" : 11000,
                        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: cockpit-api-test.groups index: roles.name_1 dup key: { : null }",
                        "op" : {
                                "_id" : ObjectId("593ad787da6a6eba2994dfb7"),
                                "name" : "GroupB",
                                "description" : "Description GroupB"
                        }
                }
        ],
        "writeConcernErrors" : [ ],
        "nInserted" : 1,
        "nUpserted" : 0,
        "nMatched" : 0,
        "nModified" : 0,
        "nRemoved" : 0,
        "upserted" : [ ]
})
BulkWriteError@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:372:48
BulkWriteResult/this.toError@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:336:24
Bulk/this.execute@src/mongo/shell/bulk_api.js:1173:1
DBCollection.prototype.insertMany@src/mongo/shell/crud_api.js:302:5
@(shell):1:1
```

what's wrong ?
thanks for feedback

**Group Model**

```
/**
 * Role Schema
 */
const RoleSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: false, trim: true, },
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

/**
 * Group Schema
 */
const GroupSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: String, unique: true, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: false, trim: true, },
  roles: [RoleSchema],
  createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is you're not inserting the `roles.name` or `roles.description` into your mongo when doing the bulk write. By default mongo will set it to null if it's not defined.

Your code at first run is inserting a null into the database because `roles` is not defined

```
{"name":"GroupA","description":"Description GroupA", "roles": {"name": null, "description": null }
```

At second run `roles` is still not defined so another null will be entered

```
{"name":"GroupB","description":"Description GroupB", "roles": {"name": null, "description": null}
```

Your `RoleSchema` doesn't allow for duplicate `name` values because you set `unique: true`

The duplicate null error is pointed out by the `"errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: cockpit-api-test.groups index: roles.name_1 dup key: { : null }"` in the thrown error.

Comment: thanks a lot... good point. the role.name required:true is guilty !